# How to access a text field value and convert to double

Tags: swift, xcode

I am working on trying to build a tip calculator using swift but am running into a multitude of problems. I have a text box where the user enters in the bill amount and then they can adjust a slider to indicate the percentage that they want to tip. I have managed to get the slider and label associated with it to work where changing the value on the slider changes the label. However, I can't figure out how to get the text field to work. I attempted to create an action for the bill amount text box being changed but no matter what I put in it, it doesn't seem like the code is ever being executed (Whenever I run the code and click in the text box, the keyboard won't go away so maybe this is part of the problem?). All that I need is to be able to access the value in the text box field inside of my action when I click the calculate button but I can't seem to even get the value to show up much less convert it to a double so I can perform calculations on it. I am super new to swift and really want to learn what I am doing wrong. I have tried multiple tutorials and similar questions on here but none of them work. I appreciate all help y'all can give.

```
    import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var txtBillAmount: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblTipPercentage: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var sldTipPercentage: UISlider!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblTipAmount: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblTotalAmount: UILabel!

    var tipPercentage = 10
    var billAmount = ""


    @IBAction func valueChanged(sender: AnyObject) {
        let currentValue = Int(sldTipPercentage.value)
        lblTipPercentage.text = "\(currentValue)%"
        tipPercentage = currentValue

    }


    @IBAction func btnCalculate(sender: AnyObject) {
        lblTipAmount.text = "\(billAmount)"

    }

    @IBAction func txtBillAmountValueChanged(sender: AnyObject) {
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //txtBillAmount.delegate = self

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    @IBAction func btnReset(sender: UIButton) {
        sldTipPercentage.value = 10
        lblTipPercentage.text = "10%"
        txtBillAmount.text = ""
        lblTipAmount.text = "--"
        lblTotalAmount.text = "--"
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

[This is a screenshot of how the UI looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wx778.png)

[Error that I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrGDH.png)

Comment: `if let text = txtBillAmount.text, let amount = Double(text) { ... }`

Comment: when I do this, I get an error saying "Cannot find an initializer for type 'Double' that accepts an argument list of type '(String)'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Xcode >= 7 and Swift > 2]**

Try like this

```
@IBAction func btnCalculate(sender: AnyObject) {
      if let textValue = txtBillAmount.text {
         let billAmnt = Double(textValue)

         let tipAmount = (billAmnt*tipPercentage)/100

         lblTipAmount.text = "\(tipAmount)"
      }
}
```

If you are using **Xcode-6 and Swift < 2** then try the following way. because `String initializer` for `Double` is only available in `Swift 2 (Xcode 7)`. [Recommend `update your Xcode`]

```
@IBAction func btnCalculate(sender: AnyObject) {
      let billAmnt = (txtBillAmount.text! as NSString).doubleValue
      let tipAmount = (billAmnt*tipPercentage)/100

      lblTipAmount.text = "\(tipAmount)"
}
```

Comment: I keep getting the error that I mentioned about when I do this and I really don't know why because you are not the first person to recommend doing the Double(txtBillAmount.text) so I really don't get why it isn't working

Comment: `Double(txtBillAmount.text ?? "")` or `Double(txtBillAmount.text!)` because textfield's text property is optional.

Comment: I tried both ways and it is still not working. This is why I came to stackoverflow, I just have no idea what's going on and everything that I've seen online has suggested these exact things but they don't work

Comment: Because this is the way it's supposed to be done. Can you please take a screenshot of the implementation and the error that's being shown.

Comment: so xcode hates me and it just won't let me do Double(textValue). I'm not sure if i'm just working with an outdate version of Xcode or what but no matter what I seem to do, whenever I try to convert the string to a double it just isn't having it. Is there any way to get around this?

Comment: Can you just log txtBillAmount.text value and tell us what you have over there?

Comment: so two things, one I'm not 100% sure what you mean by log txtBillAmount.text does that mean print it? Also, I googled how to find my version of xcode and I saw Xcode 6.4 under the command line tools so would that be the version?

Comment: Yes, update your xcode, you are a few years behind. [You need at least xcode 9.0 I believe.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/double/2926277-init)

Comment: so I am not allowed to update my xcode. The computers that we have to use don't allow for xcode to be updated.

Comment: omg it worked. Thank you soooooooo much. I really appreciate you so much thank you!

Comment: All of you can upvote this answer so other users get it useful. and you know this encourages us to help each other.